# Can't find Simplify3D installation on the computer search. Don't remember initial setup

Tags: permissions, sudo, online-accounts

I have downloaded Simplify3D (Simplify3D-4.0.0-linux-x64-installer.run) and installed it using the terminal. I've reached the directory and then installed it with sudo prefix:

```
cd /home/user/Downloads
chmod +x Simplify3D-4.0.0-linux-x64-installer.run
sudo ./Simplify3D-4.0.0-linux-x64-installer.run
```

The program launched, accepted the linked account's password and everything worked perfectly.

*Updated edit:*

Firstly, I don't understand why **I cannot find Simplify3D via search on the computer**. It is neither shown in the Ubuntu Software list. The launcher is on the Desktop, and if I delete it from there I cannot use the software anymore.
Every time I launch the program prompts a "first-time setup window" (where I choose the 3D-printer model), for some reason **the computer doesn't remember my setup**.

OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It has no other big problem at all.

**The real problem seems to be the changing IP-address:** after restarting the computer, launching Simplify3D prompts "Account Limit Reached" window (this software has a license for two computers) and says `Please uninstall the software from one of your previous installations before proceeding`. Visiting the Simplify3D website and signing in shows the account is linked to this Linux computer (and another account linked to my co-worker's Windows).

Anyways, the changing IP-address is not an Ubuntu OS related question. I will troubleshoot that with the ISP (internet service provider), try to set a static lease IP-address and of course contact Simplify3D support.

Comment: If you have a paid account, you can and should contact their customer support.

Comment: Just guessing here, but perhaps the licensing is per IP-address and you may not have a single static IP-address.

Comment: @THelper, right that seems to be the problem. How can I then have a single static IP-address?

Comment: Check if your router allows you to create something called a "static lease" or "fixed lease" IP. If it doesn't or if you want to be 100% sure you get a fixed IP every time then you need to ask your ISP for a (more expensive) subscription that includes this.

Comment: Main questions updated in the title, because the "Account Limit Reached" prompt problem seems to be caused by the changing IP-address, and is not related to Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 0):

**The first problem (settings not being stored) is a permission issue.**

When you installed Simplify3d you had to run it as root, and after the install finished you very likely clicked start Simplify3d when it was offered to you. This IMO caused the program to be run as root, which means it stored the initial settings as root and you can't change them unless you keep running the software as root.

**Regarding the launcher:**

You could use [`menu-libre`](https://launchpad.net/menulibre) to create a custom launcher in your menu for example.

**Regarding the account-limit reached issue:**

This is **absolutely** a problem with Simplify3D and their implementation of DRM, you should contact them and they will be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer nana! It is sad that I forgot the topic for a while... there is a simple reason: I surprisingly got kicked off the job, off the issued device on this topic; so I forgot about everything I was working on. Yet I appreciate the answer. The menu-libre thing sounds good. I will take it in count in future projects, because I have no license for this software anymore. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The permissuin issue is fixed by calling "AddUserPermissions.sh" from the /opt/Simplyfy3d folder with your user that you want to use.